# Custom Font Wont Load Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I am loading in a custom font, this works in every browser except IE. This is frustrating because my styling of my site is based around this font. On IE it loads in a serif font and looks terrible. Any suggestions?

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        src: url("./fonts/HelveticaNeue Light.ttf") format("opentype");
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you went to https://fontstruct.com/ and made a font, then used that in your HTML/CSS document. This, by my understanding, will always work in the latest versions of Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Opera. This may take some time, but you can also download fonts! While you are there, would you mind checking out my font? https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1437607/standard-galactic-alphabet-10

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will solve your solution

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "helvetica";
     src: url('./fonts/HelveticaNeue');
     src: url('./fonts/HelveticaNeue?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this site for more information on your topic:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx#font_and_text

[image]

Comment: @Selvin @I haz kode  I fixed the problem